# Toggle works only on one element

Tags: php, jquery

I am querying the database and for each object echoing DOM elements with database results. I am using toggle to show one variable and hide another:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name_toggle").click(function(){
        $("#hidden_onhover").toggle();
        $("#onhover").toggle();         
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
 echo "<a href=\"#\"><span id=\"onhover\">$row->common_name</span><span id=\"hidden_onhover\">$row->firstname $row->lastname</span></a>";
```

The problem is that if database returns 10 objects, I have 10 lines of results, but toggle only works on the first element. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IDs need to be unique, you should be using classes in this case.

Comment: @JonStirling thanks it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using IDs.
 It should be replaced with classes and you need to change the jQuery code accordingly.
 So your PHP code would look something like this,

```
 echo "<a href=\"#\"><span class=\"onhover\">$row->common_name</span><span class=\"hidden_onhover\">$row->firstname $row->lastname</span></a>";
```

And jQuery code would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".name_toggle").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".hidden_onhover").toggle();
        $(this).find(".onhover").toggle();         
    });
});
```

Also make sure to make `name_toggle` as a class instead of `ID`.
 Above code assumes `name_toggle` DIV is parent of `hidden_onhover` and `onhover` DIV.

Comment: Great! Please accept it as answer if its correct to help future readers.